# Update Task Project using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm trying to update a task in microsoft project online using CSOM but it's not working always return me a exception ("Unknown Error").
I'm using a example this example: 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Project-CSOM-My-Task-Checklist

Assignment assignment;

```
            // Loop through each assignment and update % complete
            for (int j = 0; j < chkAssignments.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                assignment = (Assignment)chkAssignments.Items[j];

                if (assignment.Dirty)
                {
                    if (assignment.Done)
                    {
                        self.Assignments[j].PercentComplete = 100;
                        self.Assignments[j].Comments = "teste Osmar";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self.Assignments[j].PercentComplete = 0;
                    }
                }
            }


            // Update the assignments and submit the status updates.
            self.Assignments.Update();

            self.Assignments.SubmitAllStatusUpdates("");
            projContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: where exactly are you seeing the "unknown error"?  it doesn't give you anymore detail or a line number?

Comment: @jtate when I call projContext.ExecuteQuery();

I need to update the task (Percent Complete and include Comments), but when I call projContext.ExecuteQuery(); throw me a Exception.

(Sorry, my English is bad)